# MSVS 2010. How do I assign the same version to all assemblies in a solution?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, versioning, release, release-management

Releases we publish during the development should have the same assembly version for all assemblies even if assembly was not changed from previous release.

I wonder how can I set the same version to all assemblies in the solution except doing it manually one by one inside Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1):

Usually I don't give answers recommending a product, but this is a job for an add-in. And this **free** add-in does a wonderful job for keeping version info on a solution synched

Look at [Versioning Controlled Build](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/5851/Versioning-Controlled-Build)

Beware, still it doesn't support VS2012. Work in progress....